# I cannot get past this stage of my problem: what's wrong? edx

Tags: python, edx

```
mystery_int = 3
#Write a program that will print the times table for the
#value given by mystery_int. The times table should print a
#two-column table of the products of every combination of
#two numbers from 1 through mystery_int. Separate consecutive
#numbers with either spaces or tabs, whichever you prefer.
#
#For example, if mystery_int is 5, this could print:
#
#1  2   3   4   5
#2  4   6   8   10
#3  6   9   12  15
#4  8   12  16  20
#5  10  15  20  25
#
#To do this, you'll want to use two nested for loops; the
#first one will print rows, and the second will print columns
#within each row.
#
#Hint: How can you print the numbers across the row without
#starting a new line each time? With what you know now, you
#could build the string for the row, but only print it once
#you've finished the row. There are other ways, but that's
#how to do it using only what we've covered so far.
#
#Hint 2: To insert a tab into a string, use the character
#sequence "\t". For example, "1\t2" will print as "1    2".
#
#Hint 3: Need to just start a new line without printing
#anything else? Just call print() with no arguments in the
#parentheses.
allnums = ("")
colcount = 1
rowcount = 1
for i in range(1, mystery_int):
    for i in range(1, mystery_int * rowcount):
        allnums += str(rowcount * colcount)
        allnums += "\t"
        rowcount += 1
    colcount += 1
print(allnums)
```

What's wrong? First I want to try to do it in a single string, then in a table.
Also, I don't see what hint 3 is for. Why would you need to print nothing
This is my output:
1   2

Comment: It surely helps to use different loop variables for nested loops; modifying the upper limit as you do by changing `rowcount` does not look clean either.

Comment: Just a quick bug I found: ```allnums``` is defined as a tuple but then you treat it as a string. If you want to append values into a tuple you should use ```allnums+=(str(rowcount*colcount))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Asriel. However, the code asked for something different so I made some minor edits. This is the edited version

```
mysteryList=[]
for i in range(1,int(mystery_int)+1):
 mysteryList.append(str(i) + "   ")
print(" ".join(mysteryList))
for j in range(1,len(mysteryList)):
 rowList=[str(j+1)] 
 for k in range(1,len(mysteryList)):
  rowList.append(str(int(mysteryList[k])*int(mysteryList[j])))
 print("    ".join(rowList))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what's going on with your code, but I think that this would be a better approach:

```
#We ask the user to enter misteryNumber...
misteryNumber=input("Welcome, please type the mistery number: ")
#Then we generate a list of numbers which goes from 1 to the mistery number.
misteryList=[]
for i in range(1,int(misteryNumber)+1):
 misteryList.append(str(i))
#We print the output...
print("Here are the results!")
print("-----------------------------------")
#The first row is always going to be misteryList.
print(" ".join(misteryList))
#After that we create a list for every low in wich we store its values...
for j in range(1,len(misteryList)):
 #We reset the list for each row with the first member of the list being the row number.
 rowList=[str(j+1)] 
 #A nested for loop to calculate each value within a row...
 for k in range(1,len(misteryList)):
  rowList.append(str(int(misteryList[k])*int(misteryList[j])))
 #We print the new row...
 print(" ".join(rowList))
```

Here's the output it gave my when I ran it with the number 5:

```
Welcome, please type the mistery number: 5
Here are the results!
-----------------------------------
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

PD: I don't get the point of the third hint either, python adds new rows automatically each time `print` is used (at least in python 3).